# finding the intermediate point in a line along the distance from two given points

Tags: matlab

I have written this function to find a point between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) in some distance. i am having issue of not correctly placing the point if the slope m becomes negative. Here is the code:

```
   function  [X,Y] = linE(x1,y1,x2,y2,d)
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
    theta = atand(m);
    X = x1+cumsum(d)*cosd(theta);
    Y = y1+cumsum(d)*sind(theta);
```

Comment: Your function handles positive/negative slopes just fine, the issue is that you're not accounting for your line going into the 2nd and 3rd cartesian quadrants in your calculation of `theta`. See: [`atan2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2d.html)

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your calculation is not the presence of a negative slope.

```
[X1, Y1] = linE(3, 1, 7, 10, 2);
[X2, Y2] = linE(3, 10, 7, 1, 2);
```

Both produce the correct output:

[image: correct]

The issue is when your rotations go into the 2nd and 3rd cartesian quadrants (relative to your first point):

```
[X1, Y1] = linE(7, 10, 3, 1, 2);
[X2, Y2] = linE(7, 1, 3, 10, 2);
```

[image: incorrect]

Geometrically, the result makes sense. Looking at one of our like-slope segment pairs, the slope of the segments `(3, 1), (7, 10)` and `(7, 10), (3, 1)` are both `2.25`, so `atand` is going to return about `66°` for both, when the latter is actually about `-114°`. To account for this, you can either check to make sure which quadrants you're operating in with an `if/else` block, or use MATLAB's [`atand2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2d.html) function, which is the four-quadrant inverse tangent.

Your function then becomes:

```
function  [X,Y] = linE(x1,y1,x2,y2,d)
theta = atan2d((y2 - y1), (x2 - x1));
X = x1 + cumsum(d)*cosd(theta);
Y = y1 + cumsum(d)*sind(theta);
end
```

Which produces the correct results for our 4 cases:

[image: yay]

Answer (score -2):

```
  function  [X,Y] = linE(x1,y1,x2,y2,d)
    m = abs((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
    theta = atand(m);
    X = x1+cumsum(d)*cosd(theta);
    Y = y1+cumsum(d)*sind(theta);
```

if you don't need the actual slope elsewhere.

Comment: Simply removing the sign of the slope is a bad bandaid solution. The sign is important to determine what quadrant the mapped point should be in. You are artificially placing all points to go in the first quadrant. excaza's comment on using `atan2d` is correct to account for this.

Comment: Ignoring the quadrant issue, this makes previously correct answers wrong. `linE(3, 10, 7, 1, 2)` functioned properly with the original formula and is wrong with your modification.